# How to get the timestamp for the last lock/unlock of Windows 10? (Not login/logout.)

Tags: windows-10, command-line

I previously got this command on Stack Exchange:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd /f:Text | findstr "4800 4801"
```

I get tons of output, mixed in format. Most of it looks like:

```
  Date: 2020-11-17T17:44:03.5480000Z
  Date: 2020-11-17T17:43:50.8480000Z
  Date: 2020-11-16T01:36:04.9480000Z
...
```

Those numbers are supposed to be the "last locked" or "last unlocked" events. They are **not**. They don't update when I lock/unlock the machine and re-run the command. They seem to refer to the login/logout times.

If I use:

```
wevtutil qe System /rd /f:Text | findstr "7001 7002"
```

Then I just get nonsensical output such as:

```
  Event ID: 7001
  Event ID: 7002
  Event ID: 7001
```

I've executed a million different `wevtutil` commands at this point and endlessly read cryptic help page/webpages as well as old SE questions. I keep scratching my head about the nonsensical and ever varying output I get from this command. At this point, it feels like I've tried *everything*. That command, and the entire "event log", seems fundamentally unreliable and isn't even consistent. I truly don't know what to make of this, and the Microsoft support pages feel like I'm reading text written by literal aliens from another world.

There's got to be a better, proper way to simply get the last time that the machine was locked/unlocked... right? I simply don't understand why this is even a problem. Isn't there a single, well-defined "Windows API" that you can execute on the command line to get basic stats/information like that out from Windows without needing to know everything about its internals?

How do I simply grab the date/time/timestamp for the last time the current user locked or unlocked (either is fine, but both combined is optimal) the machine?

Comment: Where did you find that command?  Because that command doesn't do what you thought it was suppose to do.  "Isn't there a single, well-defined "Windows API" that you can execute on the command line to get basic stats/information like that out from Windows without needing to know everything about its internals?" - There is but it would require the use of PowerShell and it wouldn't be single line commands for a variety of reasons.

Comment: [Just to confirm you have enabled the logging of 4800 and 4801?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11385164/eventviewer-eventid-for-lock-and-unlock#:~:text=For%20Windows%2010%20the%20event,%3D4800%20and%20unlock%3D4801.).  4800 is indeed logged when he machine is locked.  4624 is logged when a user is logged into. You will want to edit your question, adding any relevant information, instead of replying with any commentary.

Comment: @Ramhound I have not enabled the logging of anything, no. I had no idea that this was necessary, and nobody has told me about this. If this is a requirement, then I consider this to be impossible. I cannot have people sit around and fiddle around with Windows settings. This has to work on a vanilla machine.

Comment: Can you just enable it through a group policy remotely?  Did you check it was enabled? Your command was finding 2020-11-17T17:44:03.5**4800**00Z by the way not the eventID 4800, even by itself, the findstr wasn't even correct technically.

Comment: The command was searching for 4800 or 4801 on each line.  4800 does appear in those lines, within the timestamp, which of course isn't what your looking for

Answer (score 5):

First you'll want to be sure you're logging those events. open up secpol.msc go to Advanced Audit Policies on Local Computer, System Audit Policies, Logon/Logoff, in there configure "Audit Other Logon/Logoff Events" so Successes are logged. I'm new so SE is blocking my images, hopefully you can access it below. Once that's enabled those events will start being logged, if it was disabled you won't have any events logged yet.

**To view just locked times:**

```
wevtutil qe Security /q:"*[System[(EventID=4800)]]" /f:Text | findstr "Date"
```

**To view just unlocked times:**

```
wevtutil qe Security /q:"*[System[(EventID=4801)]]" /f:Text | findstr "Date"
```

**To view both lock and unlock times:**

```
wevtutil qe Security /q:"*[System[(EventID=4800 or EventID=4801)]]" /f:Text | findstr "Date"
```

The above commands however do not filter by the current user, that would give you logs from all local users. Unfortunately these logs don't store the current user in the User field, oddly, instead it's stored in the details, so there's no easy way to filter them using the simple query it offers. If you remove **| findstr "Date"** from any of the above commands, you'll instead get the full details of the logs, rather than just the times, and you could use something else to filter the users you want to see using the "Account Name:" in the Details field.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhUk8.png)